# How can I edit keystore File? expand expiry date of certificate?

Tags: android-keystore

I have lots of questions to ask about Keystore. I googled a lot but couldn't find proper answer about keystore. 
I have created my one application and I set Expiry date (accidentally small figure) too soon.. And I have uploaded my application on play store..
 So, my question is, 
**What happens after expiration date?** 
1. User's can't download application?, 
2.I will not be able to export with sign certificate? if I am able to export application than, can I able to upload it on play store? Play store accept application with expired certificate?
So I want to edit expiry date only of keystore file certificate. how can I do that?
And Once I have added validity(years): 800, what it means? 800 years? Days? After that I got expired date on **20 Dec 28**. What is calculation of expiry date here?
[image]

I have placed Image so It will be easy to understand here what I am talking about..

Answer (score -1):

The time you enter there is the expiry date in years. Google play store only allows you to use a certificate that is signed for AT LEAST 25 years.
Check this link for more information:
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html